# If statement with listView: Write to only one column?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

What i am trying to do is write to only column 5 of my listView with an if statement.

I am checking if a certain text appears in Googoel, then to put Yes in the rows that the text appears. If no then put No in the rows that the text does not appear.

Heres what I have but it keeps erroring out with `InvalidArgument=Value of '24' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index` on the No portion in the else statement.:

```
string google2 = http.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + textBox1.Text + "");
string[] embedid = getBetweenAll(vid, "type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>");

for (int i = 0; i < embedid.Length; i++)
{
    if (google2.Contains(embedid[i]))
    {
        listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add("Yes");
    }
    else
    {
        listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add("No");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error and on what line is it thrown?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair InvalidArgument=Value of '24' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `embedid.Length` to `embedid.Length - 1`.

When you use `Length` if you have 5 items, the count will be 5 however when indexing for 5 items, you will need to have `-1` because you index from `0-4` as apose to `1-5`.

Comment: Another quick question. I am trying to check if column 5 contains a Yes and if it does to write no but with the code I have its not checking the if and else statement. Its only checking the if:  if (item.SubItems[5].Text.Contains("Yes"))
                        {labelContainsVideo2.Text = "GREAT";
                            labelContainsVideo2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        }
 else
                        {labelContainsVideo2.Text = "BAD";
                            labelContainsVideo2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; }

Comment: Would the less than operator in `i < embedid.Length` not automatically stop the loop at `4` if `Length` is `5`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do it:

```
listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Item[4] = google2.Contains(embedid[i]) ? "Yes" : "No"
```